# Sorting of categorical variables using np.unique

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to get the unique values of categorical variables in sorted fashion using the below code but without success.

```
import numpy as np

unique_values, unique_value_counts = np.unique(['Small', 'Medium', 'Large', 'Medium', 'Small', 'Large', 'Small', 'Medium'], return_counts = True)

print(unique_values)
```

which gives me an output like below

```
['Large', 'Medium', 'Small']
```

However, I'm expecting output in ascending format like

```
['Small', 'Medium', 'Large']
```

Is there a way wherein I can get the categorical values in a sorted format using `np.unique()` ?

Comment: Those are just strings.  They don't have ''size' meanings to 'unique'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first translate your strings using a dictionary mapping:

```
a = np.array(['Small', 'Medium', 'Large', 'Medium',
              'Small', 'Large', 'Small', 'Medium'])
order = ['Small', 'Medium', 'Large']

key = {k:v for v,k in enumerate(order)}
# {'Small': 0, 'Medium': 1, 'Large': 2}

_, idx, unique_value_counts = np.unique(np.vectorize(key.get)(a),                                        
                                        return_index=True,
                                        return_counts=True)
unique_values = a[idx]

unique_values
# array(['Small', 'Medium', 'Large'], dtype='<U6')

unique_value_counts
# array([3, 3, 2])
```

Comment: Isnt it possible to make the dictionary mapping dynamic ? i.e the `order` (list) is manually being assigned. Is there a way to generate the same `order` (list) automatically through python code ?

Comment: What do you mean? That python would automatically identify that `Small` < `Medium`? No, this isn't possible natively. If I ask you what is the logical order of `foo`/`bar`/`baz`, what would you answer and why?

Comment: Yes, I wanted python to identify `['Small', 'medium', 'large]` automatically because its a ordinal categorical variable. As for logical order for `foo/bar/baz` it doesnt have any ordering because its a nominal categorical variable.

Comment: Well it's the same for `Small`/`Medium`/`Large` for a computer, there is no inherent meaning, those are just strings. `python` doesn't have a builtin list of categories. Only lexicographic order is supported, so you **must** be explicit and declare yourself an order.